# Having difficutly making implode statement work the way I need it

Tags: php, implode

`$id_list` is a list of numbers `10306, 10304, 10305`

I make it like this:

```
$json5 = json_decode($json4);
$id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->contact_id; }, $json5));
```

And  when I echo it with `echo "The numbers are " . $id_list;` in my `php` I get:

```
The numbers are 10306The numbers are 10306, 10304The numbers are 10306, 10304, 10305
```

I am trying to delete rows from a table, `review_shared`, where the number/s in `$id_list` do/does not exist in the `contact_id` column of the `review_shared` table.

`review_shared`:

```
user_id     contact_id
10303       10306
10303       10304
10303       10305
10303       10307
```

In this case, the last row, with `10307`, would be deleted from the table, as `10307` is not in `$id_list`.

But as it stands only the row with, `10306`, stays in the `review_shared` table. Everything else is deleted from the `review_shared` table, but only the row with `10307` should be deleted. `10306, 10304 and 10305` should stay put. Can you help?

When I hardcode `$id_list` as:

```
$id_list = "10306, 10304, 10305";
```

then my code works as intended, row with `10307` is removed from `review_shared` table and the others stay. And when I echo with `echo "The numbers are " . $id_list;` I get: `The numbers are 10306, 10304, 10305The numbers are 10306, 10304, 10305The numbers are 10306, 10304, 10305`

But `$id_list` will be changing, so I can't hard-code it in this way.

Here is my complete code:

```
      //this is the username, the logged-in user, in the user table
$user_id = 10303;

//post all phone numbers on my phone, taken from Android, as a JSON array
$json = $_POST['phonenumberofcontact'];
//$json = '[{"phone_number":"+353872934480"}, {"phone_number":"+353872934482"}]';


//decode the JSON into PHP language, will look something like ["username"] => "0871234567" etc
$array = json_decode($json);
//We want to get the corresponding user_id of the posted phone number
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
 //sanitize the query
 $stmt2 = $con->prepare($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
 //post the phone numbers of contacts from Android 
 $stmt2->bind_param('s', $phonenumberofcontact) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);

 //make the result of the query, $results, into an array
 $results = array();

  //$results = '[{"usernameMatch":"+353872934480"}, {"usernameMatch":"+353872934482"}]';
  //$results = json_decode($results);

 //for each phone number of contact posted from Android, and decoded, call it $username
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        $phonenumberofcontact = $value->phone_number;
        //get the usernames (phone numbers) that match phone numbers in our posted JSON, jsonArrayAllPhonesandNamesofContacts
        $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
        $result2 = $stmt2->get_result(); 

        //So, above, we will have our $results array - where there 
        //is a match between the posted JSON and usernames in the user table. 

        //**********************

            //we want to get the corresponding user_ids in user table of usernames
            while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {    //while 1.

            //call this user_id contact_id
            $contact_id = $row['user_id'];

             //here we get the contact_id in the user table of matching contacts
             //will be of the form [{"contact_id":"1"},{"contact_id":"27"}, etc...]
             //below we will delete these from the contacts table, if they don't exist in the most updated 
             //matching contacts.
             $contact_id_results[] = array('contact_id' => $contact_id);
             //$results of the matching usernames will be of the form [{"usernameMatch":"+123456"}, etc...]
             $results[] = array('usernameMatch' => $row['username']);

            //} 

               //Check if the contact_id which we got from the user table, for logged-in user, is in the contacts table. 
               //We use this for updating contacts who
               //who may have been added or deleted into logged-in user's contacts phone book since the last time using the app
                $query3 = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id = ? AND contact_id = ?";
                if ($stmt3 = $con->prepare($query3) or die(mysqli_error($con))) {
                $stmt3->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $contact_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt3->error);
                $stmt3->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt3->error);
                $result3 = $stmt3->get_result();
                $stmt3->close();
                } 

                //insert matching contact_ids into the contacts table, if not there already
                If ($result3->num_rows == 0) {
                $stmt4 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (user_id, contact_id) VALUES(?,?)") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $stmt4->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $contact_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt4->error);
                $stmt4->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt4->error);
                $stmt4->close();

                }

                //encode the contacts in the contacts table of this user
                $json4 = json_encode($contact_id_results);
                //$json4  = '[{"contact_id": 10306}, {"contact_id": 10304}, {"contact_id": 10305}]';
                //decode $json4, because our implode wasn't working otherwise
                $json5 = json_decode($json4);               
                //get the contact_id values as individual strings and call these $id_list
                $id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->contact_id; }, $json5));
                //echo "The numbers are " . $id_list;
                //$id_list = "10306, 10304, 10305";
                //delete any extra unnecessary contacts in the contacts table of logged-in user
                $query5 = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE user_id = ? AND contact_id NOT IN ($id_list)";
                $stmt5 = $con->prepare($query5) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $stmt5->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt5->error);
                $stmt5->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt5->error);
                $stmt5->close();


                //delete any extra unnecessary contacts from review_shared table of logged-in user, except logged-in user's own contact_id
                $query6 = "DELETE FROM review_shared WHERE user_id = ? AND contact_id NOT IN ($id_list) AND contact_id <> ?";
                $stmt6 = $con->prepare($query6) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $stmt6->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt6->error);
                $stmt6->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt6->error);
                $stmt6->close();   



                                }     //end of while 1. 

            }

            echo "The numbers are " . $id_list; 

$stmt2->close();
```

Comment: So what is the __exact__ value of `$id_list` right after `implode`?

Comment: The given code is not what generates the given output. You need to give the full code.

Comment: @u_mulder When I put my `echo` immediately after the `implode statement` I get `The numbers are 10306The numbers are 10306, 10304The numbers are 10306, 10304, 10305`

Comment: @FlashThunder The code is quite long, I was trying to be as specific as possible but I can add the lot, will edit question shortly.

Comment: can you `print_r($json5)` and update your question?

Comment: __Why__ do you have output __3 times__?

Comment: @CHarris at least give the chunk with a loop that writes "The numbers are" ...

Comment: It looks like the code you posted here is part of a more general while or for loop and that's where you should look for the solution.

Comment: Made an edit to my question, I had left out the big chunk of code as thought it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: I find it strange, as it works properly for the contacts table, but not for the review_shared table.